# A blank line is inserted at the beginning when Creating CSV using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to get the contents of the MySQL table to a CSV file. Everything works fine except that a blank row is being inserted before the heading label that I pass through Array.

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include 'auto_logout.php';
    //echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
    if ((!isset($_SESSION['ufullname'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['fullname']))) {
        /* Redirect browser */
        header("Location: index.php");
        /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
        exit();
    }
    $output = "";
    require_once('config/config.php');
    require_once("includes/ftp_settings.php");
    $table = "Download CSV"; // Enter Your Table Name 
    if (is_array($new_exist) && (is_array($ftp1))) {
        $ressd_new = 'select filename from files where uploaded_by IN ("' . implode('","', $new_exist) . '")';
        $resd_new  = mysql_query($ressd_new);
        while ($kkk_new = mysql_fetch_array($resd_new)) {
            $gotit_new = $kkk_new[0];
        }

        $resultka_new = $ftp1;

        $sql = 'SELECT slno, filename, uploaded_by, dateadded, timeadded, size FROM files where uploaded_by IN ("' . implode('","', $new_exist) . '") and filename IN ("' . implode('","', $resultka_new) . '") and size != "0"';

    } else {

        $sql = "SELECT slno, filename, uploaded_by, dateadded, timeadded, size FROM files where ftp_file  = '$ftp_server' and ftp_u_file = '$ftp_user_name' and ftp_p_file = '$ftp_user_pass' and size != '0'";

    }
    $sql           = mysql_query($sql);
    $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

    // Get The Field Name
    $heading1 = array(
        "Sl. No.",
        "File Name",
        "Uploaded By",
        "Date Added",
        "Time Added",
        "Size"
    );
    $inc = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $heading = $heading1[$inc];
        $output .= '"' . $heading . '",';
        $inc = $inc + 1;
    }
    $output .= "\n";

    // Get Records from the table

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
            $output .= '"' . $row["$i"] . '",';
        }
        $output .= "\n";
    }

    // Download the file

    $filename = "myFile.csv";
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

    echo $output;
    exit;

?>
```

Not really sure where is the blank line coming from.

Comment: Comment out the error_reporting so you see that no error is making the first line blank. You should also check all included files, if they have not the empty lines around the <?php ?> tags. And get rid of ob_start(), what is this for?

Comment: If I dont add ob_start() it does not download me a csv file. I displays the data on the browser. Also tried removing error_reporting But still the same.

Comment: The reason you need ob_start() is because the script between ob_start() and "echo $output;" is printing some content (your empty line probably). And therfore you can't set headers. I'll bet it's in your included files (auto_logout, config, ftp_settings). Allow errors, remove ob_start, solve all warnings, profit.

Comment: Atlast found out.. Thanks a lot @Reloecc. There was a white space in config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including files will often add unwanted whitespaces if not cared properly. 
Suppressing errors will make the things worse in every case.

The reason you need ob_start() is because the script between ob_start() and "echo $output;" is printing some content (your empty line probably). And therfore you can't set headers. I'll bet it's in your included files (auto_logout, config, ftp_settings).

Allow errors, remove ob_start, solve all warnings, profit.

And btw: Do not use mysql extension, use mysqli instead.